# Add Property in C# using for loop

Tags: c#

Let's say I have School model

```
public class School {

public string Name {get; set;} // property

}
```

I have a array list of Properties coming from database

```
var arraylist = ["ComputerParts","CellphoneParts"]
```

is there a way that can I add new property in School Model using for loop?

this what i'm thinking

1. for loop arraylist
2. Add new property in school model

```
//add this -> public string ComputerParts{get; set;} -> in school model
// add this -> public string CellphoneParts {get; set;} -> in school model
```

Here's the expected result

```
public class School {

public string Name {get; set;} 
public string ComputerParts{get; set;}
public string CellphoneParts {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: are you building a code generator or something? Otherwise, I don't see how the question really makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like XY Problem.

Comment: You need tell us what's you want to do, a code generator or database migration ?

Comment: sure there is a way - [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects) or [reflection + subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14724876/2716623). But this is tricky and hard to maintain (reflection + subclass way). You should avoid it at all cost!

Comment: i have a report generations task that has dynamic columns, let's say i have top 5 data the top 5 data would be the columns, and i'm using sql dapper to get the data something like this QueryAsync<DTO> my concern is how would i know which properties or columns will show in DTO or model?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string> ExtraColumns { get; }` ?

Comment: i think that would work, thanks!

Comment: @drmkc you should add that detail to the question (using your question's "edit" button), as it's quite fundamental to the context of what you're asking.

Comment: @vasily.sib you should probably make that an answer (with a bit of context added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a way to transfer some dynamic set of **key-value** pairs over network with your **DTO**. Instead of dynamicly adding properties to some class (which is actually also possible, but a lot more tricky to implement), I would suggest you to use a simple `Dictionary<string, string>` or even `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
public class SchoolDTO {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<string, string> ExtraColumns { get; set; }
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

var schoolDTO = new SchoolDTO
{
    Name = "Sample school",
    ExtraColumns =
    {
        { "ComputerParts", "part1,part2,part3" },
        { "CellphoneParts", "part1,part2,part3" }
    }
};
```